# Chaining jQuery slider and page scrolling behavior together

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to chain together a animated, horizontal jQuery slider to enable vertical page scrolling and, vice versa, have the vertical page scroll move the slider accordingly. I'm running into a couple issues that I'm not quite sure how to address.

First, when the slider is dragged (as opposed to clicked) it first pauses and then moves in the opposite direction of the drag before it begins to move in the proper direction. This is likely from the animation, but I'm not sure how to keep it animated, and still have it scroll smoothly.

```
$("#mb-reader-scrubber-bar").slider({
     animate: "slow",
     slide: function(event, ui) {
      var height = getPageHeight(),
        position = getSliderPosition(ui);
    },
     stop: function(event, ui) {
      var height = getPageHeight(),
        position = getSliderPosition(ui);
      console.log('stoppped');
      scubberSliding = false;
      $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: height * position
      }, "slow");
    }
});
```

Second, I can't get the same slow, animation effect to work on the vertical page scroll so that on page scroll it moves using a slow animation, as well as triggering the slider to move also with slow animation. I'm not sure how to animate the window on the scroll event and why the slider isn't animating (after trying many different combinations of slider initialization).

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     var height = getPageHeight(), html_scrolltop = getScrollTop();
     var perc = Math.floor((html_scrolltop / height) * 100);

    $("#mb-reader-scrubber-bar").slider("option", {
      animate: "slow",
      value: perc
   });
});
```

Here is the plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/jF3iWa?p=preview

Any suggestions on how this might be achieved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve issue #1 by checking for the event type and then animating or not:

```
if(event.originalEvent.type ===  "mousedown") {
  $('body').animate({ scrollTop: height * position}, "slow");
} else {
  $('body').scrollTop(height * position);
}
```

For issue #2, this isn't required so there's nothing to be done here and closing this question.